# Vue.js - how to display my Vue instance property in dev tools?

Tags: vue.js

I know I can add a global property like so:

`Vue.prototype.$thing = { foo: 'bar' };`

and I know I can update that instance prop with:

`Vue.prototype.$thing = Vue.observable({ foo: 'bar' })`

But how can I view this property in the dev tools? Specifically, how do I get this instance property to display in the data tree along with the other properties defined in the data prop?

Comment: VueInstance.$thing

Comment: Don't do this. It will not work in Vue 3 and is nearly impossible to test in Vue 2

Answer (score 3):

Do you use the Vue Dev Tools?

Here is an example on Firefox (chrome is similar)

access it on the console using: $vm0.$thing

[image: Vue Dev Tools]

Comment: I should have clarified, I meant how do I get the instance variable to display in the data tree in the top right panel (in your image)

Answer (score 3):

Vue's DevTools (in Vue 2) work by finding a root level Vue node (Any DOM node with `__vue__` attached to its prototype) and displaying the associated "`vm` " properties. Basically unless you use the Vue-specific ways of hooking up data, it won't show up.

It looks like you might want to add some information to some (or all!) of your components. You can do this with a [plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) or with [provide/inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject).

### Important

While you can set it based on the prototype on the Vue module, I would really suggest using the built-in capabilities of Vue to do this... mainly because your approach will *not* work whatsoever in Vue 3. There is no support for prototype modification in Vue 3 because of composition API support. Additionally, prototype modification makes it very difficult to test with Vue Test Utils and the `createLocalVue` method that you need to use for component testing.

### Plugins

Plugins are how VueI18n, VueRouter, and Vuex work. That looks like doing `Vue.use()` and then passing in a configuration object into `new Vue({})`. [The docs for plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html). In Vue 2, they actually have a secondary, headless Vue instance that they mount to manage reactive data.

I don't know what your use case is, but I would suggest using Vuex for managing reactive data throughout your components and is accessible via `this.$store` in any component. Vue Devtools also has special case logic for displaying Vuex data to the user.

### Provide/Inject

If you do not want Vuex, then you can DIY it via `provide/inject` or a Provider pattern (this is how `vue-styled-components` adds its `this.$theme` object throughout the component hierarchy). Provide/inject data is also visible in the Vue Devtools.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you declare with `prototype` and one in the `$root`'s `data` function are not the same.

`prototype` by deffinition:

> There may be data/utilities you’d like to use in many components, but
> you don’t want to pollute the global scope. In these cases, you can
> make them available to each Vue instance by defining them on the
> prototype.

So you can use this `$thing` in every child component as `this.$thing`.
([Also pay attention to conflicts](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html))

However when you declare it in the `$root`'s `data()`, you can refer to it as `this.$root.$thing` in child components.

### In summary

Declare: `this.prototype.$thing = 'foo'`

Use: `this.$thing` (in every child component)

vs

Declare:

```
new Vue({
    data() {
        return {
            $thing: 'foo'
        }
    },
});
```

Use: `this.$root.$thing`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for retrieve variables in DevTools with composition API, you need to `expose` the variables to do this.

So now you need:

```js
defineExpose({myVar: reactiveVar})
// Or shorthand
defineExpose({reactiveVar})
```

So on DevTools you can use (after selecting your component):

```js
$vm.exposed.myVar 
// Or
$vm.exposed.reactiveVar
```

You can call this expression every time the props changes in your application and it'll be updated as well.